# Excel freeze after stopping working macros

Tags: excel, vba

Let me explain.

I have a state similarity implementation in excel. One module, called a state, contains many public dictionaries at the top level.

I fill each dictionary with a huge number of object classes - mostly just data from sheets. Simple practice. The problem starts after the macro has worked normally, it leaves all these dictionaries in memory, in the task manager the Excel occupies from 2GB - this is also normal.

**State Module - Standalone module**

```
public Dict1 as Dictionary
public Dict2 as Dictionary

'Persists sheets data
public Dict3 as Dictionary
public Dict4 as Dictionary

'For persists renaming some objs
public Dict5 as Dictionary
public Dict6 as Dictionary
public Dict7 as Dictionary
```

**Class Module - Data Interface Example - clsData**

```
Public Name as string
Public Prop1 as string

Public Prop2 as Integer
Public Prop3 as Date
Public Prop4 as string

Public Value as double
```

The code below is just an example for stackoverflow. In my modules I am grabbing data from a sheet with the Range.CurrentRegion and iterate lbound to ubound.

**Another data grabber**

```
Function DataGrabberFromSheet(ByRef CurrentDict as Dict) as String

Dim i as long
Dim data as variant

Dim DataObj as clsData

set CurrentDict = New Dictionary  <--- That's recreate dict obj and start clear old data for some how, but i do not need that anymore. 

data = Sheet1.Range("A1:Q5000").Values

for i = 1 to 5000

  set DataObj = new clsData

  DataObj.Name = data(i, 1)
  DataObj.Prop1 = data(i,2)

  ...

  call CurrentDict.add(DataObj.Name, DataObj)
next


'For logging, it just an example:
If Success then
  DataGrabberFromSheet = "Success"
else
  DataGrabberFromSheet = "Bad"
endif

end Function
```

And so I decide in the debbuger to forcibly stop the program by pressing the stop button. At this point, Excel freezes for a long time, because I already have 50 or more of these dictionaries in the RAM, some of them have 200k elements each. Sometimes it takes about 300 seconds, and sometimes it instantly clears it somehow.

Old data erase by item, I think, but I do not need that data anymore. Can excel just skip that part of memory and just rewrite a new data.

How can I instantly redefine these dictionaries when the macro is rerun and not have to wait for that long cleanup? data is no longer needed at this point

Classic internet methods optimisations not solved that problem:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
...
```

Comment: Do you need to create custom objects to store the data?  You could keep the data in arrays as read from the sheet, and maybe just use a dictionary to index the first column (or whichever column you use for the dictionary key)

Comment: I do not have troubles with stores the data in dictionaries. The main issue is how to instantly clear dictionaries without wasting time. Excel sometimes does it itself, that is, it cleans about 5 million elements in all dictionaries per second, and sometimes it does it in 300 seconds. And I have a lot of data, 100-200 mb as well, and all kind of data I separate on each file. And load data from each file when it need.

Comment: Only a suggestion for an alternate approach, in the event you're not able to resolve the problem with clearing dictionaries filled with a large number of custom objects.

Comment: I have a big application now with outside self-made in app cache, this is big cost :(

Comment: I think this is a known issue with VBA - clearing a large number of objects takes a long time: regardless of whether they're stored in a dictionary, collection, or an array.

Comment: I feel a bit out of my element but what's the point of passing along a dictionary to your function if you're going to set it to a new empty one? Why not check which of the dictionaries is empty at current time and use an empty one or just don't pass along a dictionary with items in if you don't need it in said function? (sorry if this is not constructive, just trying to give a different perspective)

Comment: @Notus_Panda I have many sheets of data. Each data has own Dict, because my pipeline of calculation can reuse some sheet's data. Some sheets has similar structure, but different purpose. And example function is a cutted part of my architecture. I decide to persists required data in dicts. Writed imports functions, filter functions. Idea is not bad, but bug with dicts little annoying.

It faster, but first calc. time or after ActiveX error some time.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a known issue with VBA - clearing a large number of objects takes a long time: regardless of whether they're stored in a dictionary, collection, or an array.

For example:

```vb
Dim arr() As clsData

Sub Tester()
    Const NUM As Long = 120000
    Dim i As Long, obj As clsData, t
    
    t = Timer
    Debug.Print "---------"
    ReDim arr(1 To NUM)
    Debug.Print "Reset", Timer - t
    
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To NUM
        Set obj = New clsData
        obj.Prop1 = "Item" & i
        obj.Prop2 = "Item" & i
        obj.Prop3 = "Item" & i
        obj.Prop4 = "Item" & i
        Set arr(i) = obj
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Fill", Timer - t
    
End Sub
```

Where `clsData` is just:

```vb
Public Prop1
Public Prop2
Public Prop3
Public Prop4
```

Output from first run (after clicking "Stop" in VBE):

```txt
Reset          0 
Fill           0.34375
```

Second run:

```txt
Reset          8.601563   <<<<<
Fill           0.3554688
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion some time ago. I didn’t even suspect about it when we decided to make a big application, and most importantly, that a convenient platform is excel and access. 
All is well, but when the data went over millions of rows, I ran into this unnecessary cleanup of the top level public dictionaries in one module. Moreover, sometimes it cleans them in a second or two, but after several saves of the file it returns to cleaning hundreds of seconds again. I can't catch that moment. This thing is uncleared to me.

Comment: If your data objects are simple classes you could maybe try switching them out for UDT's...

Comment: 50/50 - sometimes, I make classes with inside methods for generating array for export or inside calc. for get another props

Also, I use UDTs too